# AWS Cognito SMS- I am unable to send SMS to Singapore number through AWS Cognito. Error: Unknown error attempting to reach phone

Tags: amazon-cognito, amazon-sns

I have a Cognito Setup which has SMS MFA enabled. Cognito user pool, SNS, PinPoint all are in Singapore region. When I add the origination number there are not many options which have SMS Enabled so I could only choose either US or Canada.

In both cases "Send Test Message" works fine while Message through Cognito as part of MFA fails with ""providerResponse": "Unknown error attempting to reach phone".

I have tried programatically as well and it works fine.

Apart from the CloudWatch logs there is no other way to debug the error.

Please help if some one has faced and resolved such issue.

Comment: Are you sending to the same phone number in both cases and only one is failing?

Comment: Yes exactly same

Comment: SMS sending works with Code as well. Just with Cognito it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: There are two separate spending limits to be set.

1. Pinpoint
2. SNS

For me Pinpoint was set but SNS was not correctly set. It all worked after increasing spending limit for SNS.

This article was useful: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cognito-troubleshoot-mfa-sms-delivery/